# Please tell me why this phrase is incorrect

Tags: grammar

I encountered this phrase while reading a local paper:

> What club does your friend a part of?

For some reason, I know that this phrase is incorrect.

I used two grammar checker websites, such as **[QuillBot](https://quillbot.com/grammar-check)**, and **[Writer](https://writer.com/grammar-checker/)**, to check whether my suspicion was valid, and I was right. Both websites corrected the phrase to these:

**QuillBot**

> What club is your friend a member of?

**Writer**

> What club is your friend a part of?

I also used **[Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/What+club+does+your+friend+a+part+of%3F)** to search for phrases that has similar construction but to no avail.

Personally, I think

> Which club is your friend a member of?

and

> What club does your friend belong to?

are correct. But I can't explain why

> What club does your friend a part of?

is incorrect. Can you please tell me the grammar rules behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the multiple results your grammar checkers have churned out is the correcting of the verb '*does*' to '*is*'.

A dictionary will tell you that these are entirely different verbs - forms of *to do*, and *to be* respectively.

*Being* a member is something a person *is*. If you were a member of a club you could say "*I am a member*" at any time, whether you were at the club or not.

By sharp contrast, *to do* something denotes an action or an event. You can't say you are doing something when you are not. One does not 'do' a membership, and that is why your original sentence is wrong. You could ask "*which club does your friend **go** to?*", because 'go' is another verb denoting an action which is *done*.

The difference between 'what' and 'which' is more dependent on the context. We use 'which' when presenting a limited choice. For example, after talking about 2 different clubs, you might ask *which* (of the two) is a person a member of. 'What' is more open-ended.